# Making API calls with Try/Catch Blocks

Tags: api, try-catch

This may be a dumb question, but do you always have to use a try/catch block when you make an API call from the internet? I can't really find an answer to this question on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not required.

These are useful for debugging erroneous code, or for resolving a situation where internet connectivity is lost, the server is down, or (for example) a cross domain request is not allowed.

APIs use them in example code to help developers and to provide an alternative to a totally bad experience to users should their server be down.

Comment: Ah, I got it! I was curious since I always see APIs with the block. Thanks!